# How to create a virtual audio input device to simulate a microphone in MacOS

Tags: macos, audio, driver

The idea is to receive an audio stream from the network and write /redirect this stream to an audio input device. As the device is not physical, i will need a virtual input. Now for virtual input device i found this [code example](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AudioDriverExamples/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html) made available by apple but not rigorously documented, but how do i write the audio stream from an application to that virtual device?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 5):

[BlackHole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) is open source. There are many useful comments in the code which might help you.